# How to add multiple currencies to product tier prices in magento2

Tags: tierprice

I have the following needs
I synchronized the products of occ system to magento2.4.5 CE, and when synchronizing the ladder prices of products, the ladder prices were multi-currency. magento2 does not use its own currency settlement rules. And I found that the magento2 ladder price defaults to USD as the benchmark currency.
[image]
How to solve the multi-currency problem at this time
Who can help me, thank you very much!

---

thank you！
If I want to add a field to the customer Group price table. It's shown after price in the figure above. How do I do this。
The end result is similar，[image]

Comment: Hi, Are you getting the all the currency prices after the conversion during sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Magento flow, there is one default base currency & the price will be converted from base currency to other currency.

So as a result, we cannot add the price in multiple currencies into the single website. One website will have only one default currency that will accept the base price.

**Solution:**

You can add the base price (as per the default currency) into the backend tier price section and Magento will automatically convert that price on the frontend to your multiple currency from base/default currency.